# td_block is not defined, ¿dónde está el error?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

El error según el Inspector de Google Chrome:

[image: Error con td_block]

Detalle del error en captura de HTML:

[image: El error en detalle]

El archivo que crea ese tag:

```
        $td_block_layout = new td_block_layout();
    $td_column_number = $td_block_layout->get_column_number(); // get the column width of the block
    $block_item = 'block_' . $td_unique_id;

    $buffy = '';

    $buffy .= '<script>';
    $buffy .= 'var ' . $block_item . '=new td_block();' . "\n";
    $buffy .= $block_item . '.id = "' . $td_unique_id . '";' . "\n";
    $buffy .= $block_item . ".atts = '" . json_encode($atts) . "';" . "\n";
    $buffy .= $block_item . '.td_cur_cat = "' . $category_id . '";' . "\n";
    $buffy .= $block_item . '.td_column_number = "' . $td_column_number . '";' . "\n";

    $buffy .= $block_item . '.block_type = "' . $block_type . '";' . "\n";

    //wordpress wp query parms
    $buffy .= $block_item . '.post_count = "' . $td_query->post_count . '";' . "\n";
    $buffy .= $block_item . '.found_posts = "' . $td_query->found_posts . '";' . "\n";
    $buffy .= $block_item . '.max_num_pages = "' . $td_query->max_num_pages . '";' . "\n";
    $buffy .= 'td_blocks.push(' . $block_item . ');' . "\n";
    $buffy .= '</script>';


    return $buffy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El inspector te está indicando que `td_block` no está definido, y de hecho en el código que has colocado de ejemplo no hay ninguna referencia a `td_block`. Comprueba que `td_block` existe y se carga antes de ser llamado.